# add time to jw player jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have the current time of a video in JW player to be added to a variable.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.playerConnect = function(player){

        var transcriptElements = this;

        player.onTime(function(evt){

                var time =  ''; 
                console.log(time);
```

I am just not sure what to put inside the empty quotation marks to get it to work properly.

Comment: Don't know this. But console.log(evt) would tell you how to get it.

Comment: Or you could try this right away. `player.getPosition()`